# 7z cli - how to pass a password with whitespaces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passwords, command-line-interface, 7zip

How to pass a password with whitespaces to the 7z cli argument `-p`?

I want to use the cli to extract a archive with a password. The p-argument is a bit ugly, because you have to write the password directly after the argument.

https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/password.htm

Following does not work:

```
7z t test.zip -pmy password
7z t test.zip -p="my password"
```

Following works, but with limitation:

```
7z t test.zip -p"my password"
```

The limitation is your password should not include quotes. Example the following will fail. The password is: `"evil quotes"`

```
7z t test.zip -p""evil quotes""
```

Because the password is now empty.

**Is there a way to pass a safe string for the password?**

The cli command is generated by JavaScript (NodeJS, exec) not manually executed in cli (windows).

Comment: can you try storing the password in a text file and using < for direction? e.g. `7z t test.zip  < passwd.txt `

Comment: Try with single quotes maybe ?

Comment: Thanks for response, but nothing works yet. Also single quotes will not help. Because I'll support any quotes. And unfortunately I can't escape with backslash. I have no idea. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. But it's a special case with the 7z cli. I should ask the developers / forum of 7z. For now I just do not support double quotes. And btw. I have no idea how special characters (utf-8) will be handled. Anyway, thanks again for advice. ...

Answer (score 0):

Places double-quotes around the flag AND password.  For example:

7z l "-pThis is password" filename.7z